Surjective homomorphism from $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{T}$
For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$, can we always find a surjective group homomorphism from $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$ (where the group operation is the matrix multiplication) to the circle group $S^1$? Starting from the (presumably) easiest case, $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$, if $\varphi: GL(2, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow S^1$ is a surjective group homomorphism, I tried to find a contradiction by working on those symmetric unitaries, such as $\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$, or $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0 \\ 0&-1 \end{bmatrix}$. However, they could all be mapped to $1$ and I do not know if this will affect the surjectivity of $\varphi$. Any hints will be appreciated.

Yes, $\mathbb{T}=S^1$ and they are the same.

Sorry for the confusion and I do not know $\mathbb{T}$ is actually an obscure notation of $S^1$.

Would $e^{i \ln |\det M|}$ suffice? (hmm maybe not)

The map $A\mapsto \log\big(|\det(A)|\big)$ is a surjective group homomorphism $GL_n(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb R$. Compose it with the map $x\mapsto e^{ix}$ to get the desired homomorphism.

In other words, we take the composition of the four group homomorphisms $\det : GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^$, $\mathrm{abs} : \mathbb{R}^ \to \mathbb{R}^+$, $\log : \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$, and $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$, $x \mapsto e^{ix}$. Each one is a surjective group homomorphism, hence the composition as well.
